# SpringBootTest with Kotlin, TestContainers and External configuration

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I have problem with creating external configuration for my test classes. Right now my redis related tests have to have a companion object inside

```
@Testcontainers
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
class RedisRelatedTest {

  companion object {
    @Container
    val container = GenericContainer<Nothing>("redis:5.0.7-alpine")
            .apply { withExposedPorts(6379) }

    @JvmStatic
    @DynamicPropertySource
    fun properties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        registry.add("spring.redis.host", container::getHost);
        registry.add("spring.redis.port", container::getFirstMappedPort);
    }
  }
  ... some tesitng
}
```

I'd like to move it somewhere outside and and use some one liner to include it but I can't find a way that works. I've created a RedisConfig class with its companion object but @Import(RedisConfig::class) or @Import(RedisConfig.Congig::class) is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

@Import(RedisConfig::class) doesn't do anything by itself, you still have to autowire a bean, did you do that as well?

One other option is to have an abstract class with a container and extend it in test classes.

Answer (score 0):

@Import(RedisConfig::class) won't work.
If it is @SpringTest you should rather use:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [RedisConfig::class])
```

but I'm not sure if testcontainer annotations will work as you expect. I solved this problem the way I described in this response to similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532851/3484423